# How to format the java map object as a groovy map

Tags: java

I am trying to generate the groovy code using java which I will be deploying on groovyscript engine for dynamic JSON data mapping. While doing this I stuck up on this problem. I am generating map object in java
in the following format.

```
 finalmap-->   {ENVIRONMENT={TEST=Functions.split(input.env.TEST,"/"), CO2=input.env.CO2}}
```

So, for converting it into groovy script map object I am using this code.

```
groovyScript.append("Map output ="+"\n"+new JSONObject(finalmap).toString(2).replace("\"", "").replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]").replace("`", "\"")+";");
String result=new String(groovyScript).replaceAll("\\\\", "\"");
```

This code will convert the map object to:

```
Map out =
[ENVIRONMENT: [
  TEST: Functions.split(input.env.TEST,"/"),
  CO2: input.env.CO2
]];
```

But as I am using lot of replace function if the key or value is having the replacing character it is replacing that also.

So, without using replace function is there anyway we could get the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following using recusrion. Indentation can be included using string format.

```
public static String mapFormatter(Map<String, Object> lhm1,String result) throws ParseException {
           result=result+"["+"\n";
           for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : lhm1.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
           if (value instanceof Map) {
                Map<String, Object> subMap = (Map<String, Object>)value;
                result=result+key+" : ";
                result=result+mapFormatter(subMap,"");
            }
           else {
                result=result+key+" : "+value+","+"\n";
            }
        }
           result=result.replaceAll(",$", "")+"]"+"\n";
        return result;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
Map<String,Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
        map3.put("at","a");
        map3.put("bt","b");
        Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("test",map3);
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("map",map2);
        map.put("id",123);
        System.out.println(map);
        System.err.println(mapFormatter(map));
}
```

output:
**This one is without formatted, using string format we can include identataion.**

```
[
    id : 123,
    map : [
    test : [
    bt : b,
    at : a
    ]
    ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [map.inspect()](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2015/09/groovy-goodness-inspect-method-returns.html)

```
def m = [a: 1, b: '1']
assert m.inspect() == "['a':1, 'b':'1']"
```